# Selenium firefox webdriver extension installation

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon

I have run into an issue involving the Selenium firefox webdriver extension installation that occurs when selenium is used. I have a small program:

```
public class SeleniumDebug
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver ff = new FirefoxDriver();
        ff.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

When I run it from home, the google site comes right up. When I run it from work, I get a popup asking me if I trust the installer of the extension. Once I click "yes", and hit the firefox restart, I get to the google page. I am using the same selenium webdriver version, and same firefox version in both places.

What could cause the difference in behavior ?? I want the "home" behavior in both places. Is the a firefox config parameter that would control this behavior?

BTW..i've seen many posts registering the issue selenium not connecting to the driver (the ole 127.0..0.1 port 7750 can't connect issue). It so happens that if the "aforementioned popup" occurs, you will get the same issue if you don't "trust" the firefox webdriver issuer.

thnx

Comment: Do you have the same FF version in the both cases?

Comment: yes, same Selenium and same FF version.

Comment: Have you done anything with profiles? It sounds like you have to fix the FF profile on your work box. You should be able to launch the default profile at work, click Yes, and then it should save the state so that it works when you run it by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncovered the issue....my company has a configuration file that gets loaded by default when Firefox is coming up. This file sets the preference key extensions.autoDisableScopes to 11 which gets in the way of the fx webdriver extension being properly loaded. As a test, I changed this value to 0, and things work as expected.